# Decode Base64, then parse CSV in Express

Tags: node.js, csv, express, base64

I have a base64 encoded csv file, and I want to process it without saving to storage. How do you decode a base64 string, then assign it to a variable and then parse it using NodeJS?

Comment: didn't you look into npm modules? It must be something there to do it, which someone else did already

Comment: look at this, for instance, https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-x it has examples. Substitute 'BASE58'  in the examples to 'BASE64'

Comment: Also what do you mean by "then parse it using NodeJS"? Why don't decode the base64 string with NodeJS too?

Comment: Yes I have looked into the npm modules, and there's only csv handler like 'csv' or 'csvtojson'. However, the front-end side of my web uses a base64 encoder to encode the csv file first, so the back-end side only receives a string. When I decode it, it becomes a regular string and I have to parse it myself, and I wonder whether it is possible to change it to csv first then parse it using 'csvtojson'. I wanted to parse the csv that the user uploaded and I want to implement it on the back-end of my web, which uses NodeJS (sorry if I made it unclear).

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want skip the decoding of the base64 string. This ain't possible practically. Even if there was a module to do this it would under the hood use the same steps: decode base64 to "normal" sting, then parse it, which is the same I suggested in the answer

Comment: No, I have decoded the incoming string. However, I'm not sure if the decoded string can be parsed using the available csv parser modules. I want to know if there are any module that can turn the string into a multipart file in the format of csv, then parse it, turn it to JSON, and save it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are many modules in the main npm repository. This is just one I chose, you can use another one. The module is [base-x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-x), the docs page has examples, which you should modify slightly to work with the base64 encoding:

```
var BASE64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
var bs64 = require('base-x')(BASE64);

var decoded = bs64.decode(youStringVariable);
// then store the decoded string or log it, or whatever
// console.log(decoded);
// myApi.store(decoded); etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is I want to turn the decoded string into a csv file without saving to storage first by assigning to a variable. Then I want to parse it and transform it as a json object, as if the variable is a csv file.